# Is this a single page website or separate web pages?

Tags: url, google-analytics

I am wondering if this is a single page website or 3 separate web pages. The URLs are:

- `index.aspx?page=home`
- `index.aspx?page=about`
- `index.aspx?page=team`

I need to know for Google Analytics purposes.

Comment: I don't think the [single-page-application] tag is appropriate to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GA will treat all of those as the same page. You will need to set up and populate a custom dimension in order to distinguish between them.